# How can I rotate a seaborn heatmap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I make a Seaborn heatmap from an upper triangle numpy array.

```
import seaborn as sns, numpy as np
a = np.random.random((20, 20))
mask = np.zeros_like(a)
mask[np.tril_indices_from(mask)] = True #mask the lower triangle
with sns.axes_style("white"): #make the plot
    ax = sns.heatmap(a, xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False, mask=mask, square=False,  cmap="YlOrRd")
    plt.show()
```

I want to rotate the plot 135 degrees clockwise. I will also be happy if the solution is not using Seaborn

Comment: What do you mean "rotate the plot 135 degrees clockwise"? What would it looks like?

Comment: I think that's a perfectly explanatory statement

Comment: Is rotating the data before plotting an option? Of course that would crop some margins as the final heatmap will be rectangular.

Comment: Absolutely , yes rotating before is fine

Answer (score 0):

You could save the image by right clicking on it and 'Save Image As', and then rotate in any image editor. Then show that image in whatever platform you prefer.

If you want to show it on Jupyter Notebook, use this:

```
from IPython.display import Image
Image(filename='path/image.png', width=400, height=400)
```